# How to navigate from listView Activity to specific tabbed fragment activity

Tags: android, listview, android-tablayout

I'm new at Android programming and I need your help. Please. What I want to do.

I created listview, from listview I created OnItemClickListener to TabbedActivity.

Now I want for each listView item to show different fragments on TabbedActivity.

This is the listView activity

```
public class BookListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_list);

        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Best Selling Books by Author");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SongListActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookList));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BookList", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my Tabbed Activity

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "HymnActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hymn);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//        if(bundle != null) {
////           HOW SHOULD I IMPLEMENT THIS
//        }

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Book1(), "Book1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book2(), "Book2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book3(), "Book3");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book4(), "Book4");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book5(), "Book5");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book6(), "Book6");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book7(), "Book7");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book8(), "Book8");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book9(), "Book9");
        adapter.addFragment(new Book10(), "Book10");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Here is my SectionsPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }


    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

This is one of my fragments

```
public class Book274 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Book274";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book274, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

So far, the tabbed fragment works very well when i slide through them. But I cant go to a specific slide. It would always start from the beginning and i have over 200 tabs

That is why i want to implement the listView tab. So that from the listView i can visit a specific tab/fragment of my choice and still slide from there forward or backwards.

Thanks Papi.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly... But maybe you can use a Master/Detail Flow as form the Android Studio Wizard and combine it with a tabbed navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first, I will attempt to answer the question you actually asked. If you want to open the "tabbed" activity to a specific tab, you need to pass the information about which tab you want to select, then tell the adapter to make that the current selection.

Your post does not clarify *how* you determine which tab you want selected, so I'm going to assume that you want the tab that matches the index of the list item you clicked on. So, if you click at the item at position 5 in the listview, you will open the tab at index 5 in the tabs list.

With that assumption...

First, pass the desired index to the tabs activity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SelectedTabIndex", i); // <- Send tab index through the intent here
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Then, in the `onCreate` of the "tabs" activity, you pull that index and tell the adapter to go there:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hymn);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("SelectedTabIndex", 0)
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index); // <- BOOM
}
```

That should be enough to get you going. If your logic for which tab you want to go to is different than just the index that was clicked, you should still be able to use the same basic idea.

Now I've answered your question, allow me to give you some unsolicited advice: given your post, if I didn't know any better, I'd say that you currently have *hundreds* of layout files and *hundreds* of classes, one for each and every book. If that is the case - *stop*. Stop *right now*. This is *completely* unmaintainable. If each fragment just represents a different book, then all you need is *one* fragment whose data is updated based on the properties of the specific book instance it represents.

Also, if you have "over 200 tabs", you're probably using the wrong UI pattern. Tabs are usually intended for a *small* amount of different data sets. If you want to see the book details of a single book after clicking its summary in a list, you probably just want to show that book *and only that book*. Not 200+ other tabs. Do a web search for "android master detail" for more info as this is a very common pattern.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks dominicoder.. it worked for me...  and as par ur advice.. You reall got it as it is..I'll check it out.android master detail.. I'm really grateful

Comment: For each tab, i wanna add a summary mediaplayer file that reads the content of the tab. can this be done in the master detail view

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure what you're asking.